# java inheritance findAll "is not mapped"

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, mapping

I have these entities :

```
@Entity(name = "PersonneSingleTableDo")
@Table(name = "personne")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "sexe", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class PersonneDo {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private int           id;
  @Column(name = "nom")
  private String        nom;
  @Column(name = "datenaissance")
  private Date          datenaissance;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "personneDo", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<AmitieDo> amis;
...


@Entity(name = "HommeSingleTableDo")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "homme")
public class HommeDo extends PersonneDo {

}


@Entity(name = "FemmeSingleTableDo")
//@Table(name = "personne")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "femme")
public class FemmeDo extends PersonneDo {

}


@Entity(name = "AmitieSingleTableDo")
@Table(name = "amis")
public class AmitieDo {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int        id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "idPersonne")
  private PersonneDo personneDo;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "idAmi")
  private PersonneDo amiPersonneDo;
...
```

I have two Daos managing my 2 inheriting classes :

```
@Repository("femmeSingleTableJpaDao")
@Transactional(value = "singletable", propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public class FemmeSingleTableJpaDao implements IFemmeSingleTableDao {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "springmvcapp_pu_singletable")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see ili.persistence.dao.IFemmeSingleTableDao#createFemmeDo(ili.persistence.bean.stratsingletable.FemmeDo)
   */
  @Override
  public void createFemmeDo(FemmeDo femmeDo) {
    entityManager.persist(femmeDo);
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see ili.persistence.dao.IFemmeSingleTableDao#findFemmeDo(int)
   */
  @Override
  public FemmeDo findFemmeDo(int idFemmeDo) {
    final FemmeDo femmeDo = entityManager.find(FemmeDo.class, idFemmeDo);
    return femmeDo;
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see ili.persistence.dao.IFemmeSingleTableDao#findAllFemmeDo()
   */
  @Override
  public List<FemmeDo> findAllFemmeDo() {
    final TypedQuery<FemmeDo> query = entityManager.createQuery("select p from FemmeDo p",
        FemmeDo.class);
    return query.getResultList();
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see ili.persistence.dao.IFemmeSingleTableDao#updateFemmeDo(int, ili.persistence.bean.stratsingletable.FemmeDo)
   */
  @Override
  public void updateFemmeDo(int idFemmeDo, FemmeDo femmeDo) {
    femmeDo.setId(idFemmeDo);
    entityManager.merge(femmeDo);
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see ili.persistence.dao.IFemmeSingleTableDao#deleteFemmeDo(int)
   */
  @Override
  public void deleteFemmeDo(int idFemmeDo) {
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.getReference(FemmeDo.class, idFemmeDo));
  }

}

@Repository("hommeSingleTableJpaDao")
@Transactional(value = "singletable", propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public class HommeSingleTableJpaDao implements IHommeSingleTableDao {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "springmvcapp_pu_singletable")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see ili.persistence.dao.IPersonneDao#createPersonneDo(ili.persistence.bean.PersonneDo)
   */
  @Override
  public void createHommeDo(HommeDo hommeDo) {
    entityManager.persist(hommeDo);
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see ili.persistence.dao.IPersonneDao#findPersonneDo(int)
   */
  @Override
  public HommeDo findHommeDo(int idHommeDo) {
    //    final TypedQuery<PersonneDo> query = entityManager.createQuery(
    //        "select p from PersonneDo p where p.id = :id", PersonneDo.class);
    //    query.setParameter("id", idPersonneDo);
    //    return query.getSingleResult();
    final HommeDo hommeDo = entityManager.find(HommeDo.class, idHommeDo);
    return hommeDo;
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see ili.persistence.dao.IPersonneDao#findAllPersonneDo()
   */
  @Override
  public List<HommeDo> findAllHommeDo() {
    final TypedQuery<HommeDo> query = entityManager.createQuery("select p from HommeDo p",
        HommeDo.class);
    return query.getResultList();
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see ili.persistence.dao.IPersonneDao#updatePersonneDo(int, ili.persistence.bean.PersonneDo)
   */
  @Override
  public void updateHommeDo(int idPersonneDo, HommeDo personneDo) {
    personneDo.setId(idPersonneDo);
    entityManager.merge(personneDo);
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see ili.persistence.dao.IPersonneDao#deletePersonneDo(int)
   */
  @Override
  public void deleteHommeDo(int idHommeDo) {
    //    final Query query = entityManager.createQuery("delete from PersonneDo p where p.id = :id");
    //    query.setParameter("id", idPersonneDo);
    //    query.executeUpdate();
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.getReference(HommeDo.class, idHommeDo));
  }

}
```

I have a JUnit testCase that test all the methods : The persist, the find and the update works fine, but I have two problems :

First, The findAll methods doesn't work, on either Dao. It output these errors :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: HommeDo is not mapped [select p from HommeDo p]
and
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: FemmeDo is not mapped [select p from FemmeDo p]
```

Second, when I remove a Man('Homme') that was friend('amis') with another and i retrieve(find again) this second person, it still lists the first Man as friend, despite the cascading annotation :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "personneDo", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Could you help me understand why and resolves these two problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Annotation `@Table` for the `HommeDo` and `FemmeDo`

```
@Table(name = "table_x")
```

Also, if you do not use the `name = "HommeSingleTableDo"` from `@Entity` annotation, then remove it. For example:

```
@Entity
```

Comment: It's an inheritance by SINGLE_TABLE if I put Table in inheriting classes i get : févr. 26, 2014 6:31:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
WARN: HHH000139: Illegal use of Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: ili.persistence.bean.stratsingletable.HommeDo
févr. 26, 2014 6:31:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
WARN: HHH000139: Illegal use of Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: ili.persistence.bean.stratsingletable.FemmeDo

Comment: It is because you have `@Table` at your `PersonneDo` class. So when you are extending this class, it gets two annotation on those two classes.